# Windows authentication does not exist in IIS Features?

Tags: windows-7, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I do not know why, but I can **not activate Windows Authentication** for **IIS** and many other feature, as they are all missing in the security section for Programs "Windows Features".
As the photo below

I really hope someone would help me

I **already try to unistall IIS** and reinstall
I use Windows 7 O.S Professional

And this  **worked fine last week** on my computer , but not now .. I don't know why :'(

**Sorry** on the picture it's all in french ^^ But almost same in english ;-)

[image]

### I miss this features -> with a [?]

[image]
[image]

Comment: But i can not enable them, If you see my first pictures on "Security Tab" from "Windows Features" window, they miss a lot of functionality . It miss "Windows Authentication" section .. so i can not enable it. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Mhh maybe you didn't understand, i had a new picture on my description. You saw now ? I miss the feature with the "?" on the picture in tab security

Comment: My list look like no complete .. and don't know why

Comment: You sure both feature lists are from the same version of IIS?

Comment: yes i'm sure . Cause last week , this list was complete . [IIS V.8]

Comment: And i think all IIS version maybe since iis 6.0 have windows authentication

Comment: The only time I've seen this was when using Windows 7 Home Premium.  It does not include Windows Authentication in IIS.  You say, that you have Windows 7 Professional, so that wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Yes , that why it's really weird .. And last week all worked well